# Why does the ImageButton width not adjust to the new width?

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I'm migrating an app from Xamarin to MAUI and I'm having layout issues. One of the problems is that the ImageButton doesn't seem to use it's new width when a HeightRequest is set (and AspectFit). The image varies in size and ratio, and therefore a set width isn't an option (the code below is greatly simplified, IRL its a custom control). The original image is large and can't have a fixes size. I do not know the aspect ratio for the image, and although I could create an image based on the source, and measure it, I was hoping for a better solution in terms of performance.

The questions are:
Why is the behavior different?
And how do I fix this?

Tested on iOS.

```
<StackLayout HeightRequest="300" Padding="0,100">
    <Grid BackgroundColor="Aquamarine" HeightRequest="200">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ImageButton Source="cup.png"
                     BackgroundColor="HotPink"
                     x:Name="btn"
                     HeightRequest="80" 
                     Aspect="AspectFit" 
                     HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                     VerticalOptions="Start">
        </ImageButton>
        <Label BackgroundColor="Coral" Text="My nice cup" Grid.Column="1"></Label>
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

In the button clicked eventhandler the Width is 2000, and that's why the label isn't visible at all.

**Xamarin**
[image]

**MAUI**
[image]

Comment: I have worked on Maui for more than a year now already and I can assure you a lot of XAML interactions have changed from Xamarin to Maui, the things Maui does makes more sense as well. So in your case since you are not assigning a fixed width be it Via the Grid's Column Def or through a Width Request, the interaction that you get here is logically correct

Comment: Would you know where I can find documentation regarding the ImageButton changes?

Comment: The change is not in the ImageButton rather its the changes to StackLayout and Grid that are affecting you here, let me check their Github if I can find something relevant, `Update` this looks relevant https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/layouts

Comment: I read through those docs, but there is no mention of the ImageButton or Image behavior. I tested with Image and it's the same thing. I have to specify the width, I cant just use height request and aspect fit

Comment: Also i don't recommend using `StackLayout` unless you wanna change the orientation Runtime, Since the new Vertical/Horizontal Stacklayout are rewritten versions of Stack that will probably be better. Go through this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/grid and you might understand the changes to the new Grid

Comment: Well, the new Grid does not perform Runtime Calculations for Columns Marked as Auto and hence does not try to handle Aspect, If you say a Column is Auto and the ImageButton Request 1000 pixels it will be allotted a 1000 pixels. Ergo the new warning in Maui Grid Docs

Comment: The StackLayout is just example code. The actual code is quite complex (custom control with handlers etc). I tried using other layout controls, for example HorizontalStacklayout, but the same problem. WidthRequest seems to be required albeit AspectFit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254955/discussion-between-freakyali-and-iris-classon).

Comment: I did a tested based on your code, whether I'm running on a Xamarin project or maui, the effect is the same.

Comment: With the exact same code? On iOS? I tried even with Image instead of ImageButton, and Android renders as expected, while iOS does not. Which version are you using?

Comment: I tested on iPhone 14Pro emulator with iOS 16.4.

Comment: I noticed that the second column of your `Gird`  in your image is `*`(`<ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>`), while the code above you set a fixed width(`<ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>`).